# Problem booting from a DVD: How do I eject the DVD?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp

I tried to install Windows 7 on Bootcamp, but the Windows 7 boot CD has a boot problem about code 5.
The Windows 7 installation DVD is in the DVD driver. How can I eject the DVD from the drive, and boot normally?

Comment: Is it an Intel based Mac?

Comment: Easiest way around this is to hold ALT/OPTION key during boot (right when you here the "bbaauuummm" tone). It'll give you a list of devices you can boot from. Select your primary partition (the one with OS X) on it. Once booted into OS X, you can then just eject the DVD normally.

Answer (score 5):

If it's an Intel based Mac, [you can press either F12, or Eject, or the Mouse button on startup](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1533).

Comment: And if our mac is stuck wanting to boot from a broken Windows installation hold the Option key as the machine boots.  You'll be presented with a boot menu.

Comment: @Dustin - Good point.

Comment: Bootcamp. It must be an Intel Mac.